# Applying a function to each row to check against another vector

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a vector of numbers

```
my.vec <- c(244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258)
```

I have dataframe

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:10), x1 = sample(190:285,10, replace = T), x2 = sample(200:350,10, replace = T), x3= sample(100:280,10, replace = T), x4= sample(250:350,10, replace = T), x5 = sample(150:300,10, replace = T))
```

I want to make another column in `df` which shows for each loc.id (or for each row), what percentage of `my.vec`occur in columns x1 to x5. I managed to do this.

```
apply(df[,2:6],1,function(x) x %in% my.vec)
```

this gives me TRUE or FALSE if elements in a column occur in my.vec. I just need to find some way to express it as percentages

Comment: Percentage of `my.vec` represented or percentage of each row?

Comment: Also, it might be nice to do a `set.seed` before creating `df` so that the answers are all working with the same source data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in `ColMeans` and multiply by 100:

```
df$new_col = colMeans(apply(df[,2:6],1,function(x) x %in% my.vec)) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `dplyr` approach to getting the row-wise proportion of values in `my.vec`:

```
df %>% mutate(
  prop.my.vec = df %>% 
    select(starts_with("x")) %>% 
    mutate_all(funs(. %in% my.vec)) %>% 
    rowSums() / 5
  )

#    loc.id  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5 prop.my.vec
# 1       1 225 332 226 292 215         0.0
# 2       2 194 306 273 282 216         0.0
# 3       3 258 310 138 269 264         0.2
# 4       4 253 340 219 266 200         0.2
# 5       5 213 268 267 302 209         0.0
# 6       6 218 289 244 342 185         0.2
# 7       7 246 323 112 270 160         0.2
# 8       8 222 233 170 332 287         0.0
# 9       9 249 262 173 252 266         0.4
# 10     10 242 205 219 343 166         0.0
```

Comment: Pretty much the same logic in base R functional methods - `Reduce(\`+\`, lapply(df[-1], \`%in%\`, my.vec) ) / length(my.vec)`

Comment: Is there any way I can replace the 5 (which is the no. of columns) by something more generic since I plan to use this for other dataframe which would have different number of x columns

Comment: If it's a consistent layout (ID and then all columns columns right of this to be handled) then replace the 5 with `length(df)` (likewise for the accepted answer change `2:6` to...  `2:length(df)`